# Подскажите те, кто знает Unity

Tags: unity3d

Вопрос! Как сделать спрайт/объект(2д,3д) зависимым от другого спрайта/объекта. Т.е. чтобы при создании объекта они делили текстуру. Например конвейер: у него есть Начало(1), середина(2),углы(3),конец(4)- и это все спрайты. Мы создаем какой-нибудь конвейер 1223224 и текстуры соединяются между собой и подстраиваются под направление( подстраиваются углы )

Comment: Tilemap rules? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ky0sV9pua-E

Comment: Спасибо, а  на 3d есть?Ну или 2.5Д

Comment: 2.5D не существует

Comment: 3D тайлов в юнити нет, но вам ничего не мешает реализовать это самостоятельно. 2.5D - это лишь иллюзия при помощи 2D тайлов, т.е. решение по ссылке выше будет здесь работать.

Answer (score 0):

Объекты можно сделать зависимыми друг от друга при помощи скриптов.

Например, можно сделать один скрипт-менеджер и в нем реализовать связь (например, объявить в нем массив объектов со спрайтами + описать логику их связи). А можно в каждом из объектов сделать свой скрипт (тогда удобнее будет сделать одинаковые скрипты с разными настройками для всех разновидностей частей конвеера), в скриптах настроить ссылки на соседние части конвеера и описать логику.

Что касается разделения текстур между спрайтами, то они и так разделяются (в 3D варианте это будут материалы).